# Cancel thumbnail url change PHP

Tags: php

There's a plugin in the CMS that I'm using that generates thumbnails from an uploaded image. The thumbnails are located in a certain folder, and the filename is changed to include the width and height, as well as change the file extension to '.jpg'

So if the original file is
domain.com/files/project/project-name/image.png
the thumbnail is
domain.com/files/cache/image.50x50.jpg

but I want it to just be 'image.png' like it is in the original file.

The problem is, the plugin that uses this plugin responds poorly to this because I need to keep the original filename stable. I don't know /anything/ about PHP, and so I don't know what exactly I should delete from the code in order for this to happen.

I guess it's somewhere in this piece of code

```
$file_extension= substr( $thumbnail , strrpos( $thumbnail, '.' ) );
$cache_file_name= str_replace( $file_extension, "", $thumbnail ) . "." . $width . "x" . $height . "_" . $adaptive . ".jpg";
```

but I don't know how to retain the file extension.

The original code is:

http://pastebin.com/Bu8gJN79

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
$file_extension= substr( $thumbnail , strrpos( $thumbnail, '.' ) );
$cache_file_name= str_replace( $file_extension, "", $thumbnail ) . "_" . $width . "x" . $height . "." . $file_extension;
```

But I would still advise you to have different name of some sort. Mybe (immage_thumbnail.jpg) or something. Since this is kinda the "best practice"

Comment: I guess the 50x50 portion of the file name is okay, but I really want to retain the original file extension of the file name (which, in the example is `png`. How do I retain it?

Comment: sumthing like that then. Updateed the answer

Comment: D'oh! I had thought that using `$file_extension` would return nothing because of the `str_replace` function! There was a $ missing from your code but apart from that, it worked splendidly, thank you!